# vim quick get to last set of single quotes

Tags: vim

So I am in the process of learning vim. So if I want to get to the last set of the single quotes, how would I do that efficently?

```
Plug 'OrangeT/vim-csharp', { 'for': 'csharp' }
```

Here are the ways that I thought of doing it, but I am sure there is a quicker way to do it.

- Hitting w a few times
- Doing a f ' and repeating it a few times

Comment: There’s probably some elegant way, but in practice I’d do `$2F'`. See also [Vi.SE].

Comment: I would probably do your second one where the repeating was done with `;`

Answer (score 3):

Another way: `$B`

1. `$` go to the end of the line
2. `B` jump to the beginning of the previous "word"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`G` to get to the end of the file (not sure if you want that or not)

`$` to get to the end of line

`?'<enter>` to reverse search for a `'`

`n` to find the next occurrence (which would be the 2nd to last one)

Update: @minitech suggests a good way in the comment above